# Problems with QGIS 3D animation in Windows

Tags: qgis, 3d, animation

When I use the 3D map view in QGIS 3.10 on Windows 10 and animate a map all the pictures turn out black. I can click the export button and get an actual picture. I have reformatted the computer and reinstalled QGIS with the same problem. It works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 with the same data. Any ideas what might be wrong.

Currently I have a Toshiba Portege M780 with Windows 10 Professional and stock video drivers.

It has been a while since I last tried to get this to work, but I think I have tried multiple computer, but all with stock drivers.

Comment: most likely it is graphics drivers on windows what is your setup on windows?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My first post not sure if it is better to edit the original post or add comments.  But I edited the original post.

Comment: GMA5700MHD is the graphics cards drivers are available via intel (but only windows 7) so you might have a compatibility issue with windows 10 potentially. see https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81503/Intel-HD-Graphics-for-Previous-Generation-Intel-Processors